# Why we don't need to cover all possibilities in calculating expected value

Tags: expected-value

`We choose 10 cards at random from a standard deck of 52 cards. Find EV of the number of aces.`

 If we pick a card and then replace it back EV is `10*1/13.` 

 Why the EV is also `10*1/13` when we get an ace and don't put it back , why don't we need to cover all possibilities here?

 EV : Expected Value

Comment: How is the result different when you cover all possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Expectations are additive , that is for random variables $\ X,Y\ $ we have $$E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$$

If we define $\ X_j=1\ $ if the $\ j\ $-th card is an ace and $\ 0\ $ otherwise, the sum $$X_1+\cdots +X_{10}$$ is the number of aces. Since every $\ X_i\ $ has expectation $\ \frac{1}{13}\ $, the total expectation is $\ \frac{10}{13}\ $

Comment: Yes But after picking a aces shan't the  next probability 3/51 ?

Comment: The probability changes in fact, but every single card has the same probability to be an ace, if we know nothing about the other cards.

Comment: @ToufiqueImam $\frac{3}{51}$ is the **conditional** probability that *given* that we first drew an ace that the second card is also an ace.  Note that if we weren't to condition on the result of the first draw the *unconditional* probability that the second card is an ace is $\frac{4}{52}$, just like the first draw, or really any of the draws.

Comment: Additionally, if we *didn't* draw an Ace on the first card, the conditional probability that the second card is an Ace is $\frac4{51}>\frac1{13}$, so if you want to take all the possibilities into account  you have to consider this, too.  Linearity of expectation is the way to go.